# Creating an application with react-native init AwesomeProject

Tags: react-native-windows

I am new to react native and i try creating a project with "react-native init AwesomeProject" but got this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtHpT.png)

and I try checking the folder AwesomeProject, android and ios folder are missing, am working on windows 10

Comment: Just read the guide.

Comment: I did over and over again, I even uninstall and install

Answer (score 0):

This error is a new bug in react-native 0.56 that affects Windows users. To solve it you can create a project with another react-native version:

```
react-native init --version="0.55.4" MyNewApp
```

You can see more infos in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20015).

And.. Remember to run "npm install" before starting your project.